# Performing PCA for normal score transformed data

Tags: bayesian, pca

In an attempt to improve the results of Bayesian NNT, I transformed the 7 variables that I have into normal scores (subtracted the mean and divided by SD).
Then I used a PCA on the transformed variables to generate new 7 PCs. I used these PCs to run the Bayesian NNT and the classification results improved a little bit.

My question is is this statistically valid and applicable or does it violate some fundamental statistical rules?

Comment: I think you should detail the context of your question. Tell us more about the NNT and the variables, explain what is the classification about... This will be really helpful in answering your question.

Comment: **What is NNT?**